# How to add commands to Ant build xml

Tags: java, xml, ant

I would like to run the command `javac -version` when the Ant does it build on Linux. I did a bit of reading and wrote my xml as follows:

```
<javac srcdir="SourceDir" destdir="DestDir" executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}">
    <classpath>
       ....
    </classpath>
<compilerarg value="javac -version"/>
  </javac>
```

But i get an error as follows:

```
[javac] javac: invalid flag: javac -version
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options
```

What is the issue? How can i make Ant print the jdk version that it is using when running the javac command. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<project> 
   <echo>Java Version via Ant: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
   <echo>Java Version System Prop: ${java.version}</echo> 
</project>
```

or

```
<target name="print-version"> 
   <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
   <echo>Java/JVM detail version: ${java.version}</echo> 
</target>
```